# MATLAB equivalent command of robust SE used in Stata

Tags: matlab, stata

What is the MATLAB equivalent command of robust standard error in linear regression in Stata (e.g. `reg y x, robust`)?

I guess HAC might be the answer (http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/hac.html).

Can anyone show a simple example of MATLAB that can generate the same result as generated with Stata code listed below.

```
webuse iris, clear
reg  seplen sepwid
reg  seplen sepwid, r
```

In MATLAB, I found robustfit (http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/robustfit.html), but it should not be the equivalent command as it will affect the value of the estimated beta value, what's the relation between robustfit and robust standard error?

Comment: Robust (resistant) regression, featuring alternatives to least squares,  is nothing to do with robust standard errors in regression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by Nick Cox in a comment, you're not going to use *robustfit*. Instead you're going to estimate the robust standard errors separately like in the following little piece of code using *hac*.  The coefficient estimates are found using the *fitlm* command.

```
% Load/define data
load fisheriris;
sepwid = meas(:,2);
seplen = meas(:,1);

% Estimates
fit = fitlm(sepwid,seplen);
[~,SE,coef] = hac(fit,'type','HC','weights','HC1','display','off');

% Output non-robust
fit.Coefficients(:,1:2)

% Output Robust
[coef SE]
```

Note that MATLAB places the constant/intercept in the top rather than in the bottom (like Stata). Alternatively you can use *regstats2* by Oleg Komarov (*), which will give you p-values etc. as well.

```
% Estimates
fit2 = regstats2(seplen,sepwid,'linear','all');

% Output
[fit2.beta fit2.hc1.se]
```

(*) http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26169-regstats2

Comment: Cool answer! But I notice the "fitlm" and "hac" are only introduce in 2013 version of the matlab, any alternative command if I used the previous version of matlab (R2010a), I guess I can use "regress" to replace fitlm, which command to replace hac, is it available?

Comment: Noted, it works! How can I get the SE without correction in regstats2?

Comment: Additionally, since the rapid advance of the function for linear regression in recent version of matlab, is there any very recent book that devote to focus on this within the filed of econometrics?

Comment: Replace *hc1* with *hc0* to get the se's without the small sample correction. Unfortunately I cannot point you towards any book references.

Comment: Cool. I found a basic one that might be useful:http://people.brandeis.edu/~pmherb/MatlabBootCamp/index.html